# How to recalculate the the length of a geography linestring from nearby geography point in POSTGIS?

Tags: postgis, linestring, geography-data-type

I have a geography type linestring
*route_geography geography(LineString,4326)*, its a route from point A to point B. Now I have a point C near that line. I want to find the nearest point on that line, lets call it D. And then calculate the distance between D and B.

Should I use *ST_Line_Locate_Point()* to find the point D?

And if I do find the point D should I then use *ST_Line_Substring()* to split up the AB linestring to make a new DB linestring?

These two functions are for geometry type not geography that my data is in, so what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to multiply the return value of ST_Line_Locate_Point by the route length to get the length from A to D, since

> ST_Line_Locate_Point — Returns a float between 0 and 1 representing the location of the closest point on LineString to the given Point, as a fraction of total 2d line length.

For D to B use

```
(1 - ST_Line_Locate_Point) * lenghtA-B
```

Comment: My own solution to get length from D to B was: ST_Length(   
 ST_Line_SubString( linestringAB, 
      ST_Line_Locate_Point(linestringAB, 
                           pointC), 
      1
   )::geography) - but your solution gives almost same results. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need a combination of ST_Line_Interpolate_Point and ST_Line_Locate_Point, using the terms of your example, and asuming that you already have a linestring of your path from A to B,

```
ST_Distance_Sphere( ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(lineAtoB, ST_Line_Locate_Point(lineAtoB,pointC) ), pointB)
```

Comment: I tested your solution with real data and results were off. Haven't yet analyzed why.